# How to extract xml attribute from a column?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a column called `target_data` in the `sys.dm_xe_session_targets` that returns the path where the pertinent file resides in the format of xml tags. 
This data is not in XML datatype. One has to cast it to the XML data type.

This is how the typical field in the column looks like:

```
  <EventFileTarget truncated="0">
  <Buffers logged="135" dropped="0"/>
  <File name="C:\ExtendedEvents\degree_of_par\deg_of_par_0_130897981436560000.xel"/>
  </EventFileTarget>
```

I want to retrieve the `name attribute` of the `file tag` i.e. `C:\ExtendedEvents\degree_of_par\deg_of_par_0_130897981436560000.xel` in this case.

I tried the following script for the same, however it is throwing errors:

```
select xe.m.value('EventFileTarget/file/@name[1]','nvarchar(500)'),*
from sys.dm_xe_session_targets as s
cross apply (select cast(target_data as xml) as m) as xe
```

The error reads :

> Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XQuery [xe.m.value()]: 'value()'
>   requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type
>   'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

I'm perplexed. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XQuery expression in the `value()` function must return at most one value.

Your expression `EventFileTarget/file/@name[1]` is saying that from all `EventFileTarget`nodes you want all `file` nodes and from those nodes you want the first `name` attribute.

Given this sample XML:

```
<EventFileTarget>
  <file name = "FileName 1"/>
  <file name = "FileName 2"/>
</EventFileTarget>
<EventFileTarget>
  <file name = "FileName 3"/>
  <file name = "FileName 4"/>
</EventFileTarget>
```

Your expression returns all four filenames.

Change the XQuery to `(EventFileTarget/file/@name)[1]` to get the first `name` attribute with the path `EventFileTarget/file`.

With XML that looks like this

```
<EventFileTarget>
  <file/>
  <file/>
</EventFileTarget>
<EventFileTarget>
  <file/>
  <file name = "FileName 4"/>
</EventFileTarget>
```

The result `(EventFileTarget/file/@name)[1]` is `FileName 4`.

In your case there can probably only be one `EventFileTarget` node and only one `file` node but SQL Server does not know that so you have to build the XQuery to guarantee only one value returned. `(EventFileTarget/file/@name)[1]`.

Comment: If only Books Online were written like that.  Thanks @Mikael !